Indicating deceased individual using Family Tree Maker and Ancestry
I use Family Tree Maker 2019 and sync with an Ancestry tree. What is the best way to indicate to the algorithm that an individual is deceased if I don't have any birth or death dates? I know the algorithm is supposed to figure it out based on other relatives' dates, but that often fails and Ancestry assumes the individual is alive. I was typing in "deceased" when I was unable to estimate a date, but I think that might be a problem if I want to export a Gedcom file because it's not listed in The Gedcom Standard.

Your link is to the GEDCOM 7.0 standard. Neither Family Tree Maker nor Ancestry export to GEDCOM 7.0. They both export to GEDCOM 5.5.1.

In Ancestry, go to the person's profile. Then from the top right, select "Quick Edit" from the Edit dropdown.

Then from the Quick Edit window, change the Status of the person from "Living" to "Deceased".

This will add "Death date" and "Death place" fields to the bottom of the Quick Edit window. But if you do not know the date or place, you can leave them both blank. Then press the "Save" button and the person will be known by Ancestry to be deceased.
You will see that the person who was previously listed as "DEATH Living" will now be listed in Ancestry as: "DEATH Unknown"
Family Tree Maker 2019 is similar. Add a Fact, select "Death" as the fact, and if you don't know the death date or place, then don't enter them.
The correct way to export a status of "Death" in GEDCOM when the date and place is not known is to export it with the DEAT tag followed by a "Y" (for Yes), e.g.:
0 @I65@ INDI
1 NAME ??? /???/
1 DEAT Y

When exporting to GEDCOM, Family Tree Maker will include the "1 DEAT Y" line correctly.
Unfortunately Ancestry does not include this line. So if you want to export to GEDCOM for input into some other program, an export from Ancestry will not transfer deaths with no date and no place correctly.
I do not know if a death status with no date and no place will Sync correctly both ways between Ancestry and Family Tree Maker. Hopefully it does. But if it only Syncs correctly one way, then always add a death status with no date or place to the system that will correctly Sync.
